# What is the best, worst and average case running times of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science

What is the best, worst and average case running times of an algorithm?

Comment: I removed "operating-systems" tag, since it does nothing with the question.

Comment: Yes...but I couldn't find a perfect answer

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic here. This is not really a programming issue, but a theoretical computer science question, so it should have been asked on Computer Science Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In the simplest terms, for a problem where the input size is *n*:

- **Best case** = fastest time to complete, with optimal inputs chosen.
  For example, the best case for a sorting algorithm would be data that's already sorted.
- **Worst case** = slowest time to complete, with pessimal inputs chosen.
  For example, the worst case for a sorting algorithm might be data that's sorted in reverse order (but it depends on the particular algorithm).
- **Average case** = arithmetic mean.  Run the algorithm many times, using many different inputs of size *n* that come from some distribution that generates these inputs (in the simplest case, all the possible inputs are equally likely), compute the total running time (by adding the individual times), and divide by the number of trials.  You may also need to normalize the results based on the size of the input sets.

Complexity and running time are often expressed in "Big O notation," which is used to describe the approximate amount of time an algorithm requires to complete, based the size of its input.  Rob Bell wrote an [excellent overview](http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/) with very clear examples.

The most commonly used Big O descriptions are

- **O(1)** always terminates in about the same amount of time, regardless of the input size.
- **O(logN)** takes a fixed additional amount of time each time the input size doubles.
- **O(N)** takes twice as long to finish if the input size doubles.
- **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** takes four times as long if the input size doubles.
- **O(2<sup>N</sup>)** increases exponentially as the input size increases.

You can see from the table below that the difference is small for small input sizes, but it can become tremendous as the input size increases even a little bit.

```
Input Size              Time to Complete
               O(1)  O(logN)   O(N)   O(N2)   O(2N)
     1           1       1      1       1       1
     2           1       2      2       4       4
     4           1       3      4      16      16
     8           1       4      8      64     256
    16           1       5     16     254   65536
```

Comment: And wrong. First, all three are w.r.t a fixed input size `n`. Otherwise, "worst" or "best" might not be well defined. Secondly, average case means to take the average over *all* inputs (of this given size), weighted with some probability distribution (typically uniform).

Comment: It is also important to note that best-case or worst-case has nothing to do with the input size. It has to do with the nature of the input. E.g. whether the list is already sorted.

Answer (score 4):

**Worst Case Analysis (Usually Done)**
In the worst case analysis, we calculate upper bound on running time of an algorithm. We must know the case that causes maximum number of operations to be executed. For Linear Search, the worst case happens when the element to be searched (x in the above code) is not present in the array. When x is not present, the search() functions compares it with all the elements of arr[] one by one. Therefore, the worst case time complexity of linear search would be Θ(n).

**Average Case Analysis (Sometimes done)** 
In average case analysis, we take all possible inputs and calculate computing time for all of the inputs. Sum all the calculated values and divide the sum by total number of inputs. We must know (or predict) distribution of cases. For the linear search problem, let us assume that all cases are uniformly distributed (including the case of x not being present in array). So we sum all the cases and divide the sum by (n+1). Following is the value of average case time complexity.

**Best Case Analysis (Bogus)** 
In the best case analysis, we calculate lower bound on running time of an algorithm. We must know the case that causes minimum number of operations to be executed. In the linear search problem, the best case occurs when x is present at the first location. The number of operations in the best case is constant (not dependent on n). So time complexity in the best case would be Θ(1)

Comment: Source - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-2-asymptotic-analysis/

Answer (score 2):

Think of an algorithm as a program.  This program takes some data, churns on it for a while, and then spits out an answer.  Of course, we care about how long the program churns on the data before giving the answer.

But there's a catch: for many algorithms, running time depends on the data itself.  Many sorting algorithms are faster for already-sorted data, for instance, and some are slowest for data that's sorted in reverse order.

So let's think about where that data comes from.  Maybe your best friend gets to pick the data.  Your friend picks data that causes your program to run quickly, and we call that runtime the best case, since the algorithm will never do better than that.  Maybe your worst enemy (in textbooks, this is called the adversary) gets to pick the data.  Your worst enemy picks data that causes your program to run slowly, and we call that runtime the worst case because the algorithm will never do worse than that.  And maybe a giant roulette wheel gets to pick your data.  Then, you can run your algorithm on a bunch of roulette wheel data, and average all the runtimes to get the average case time.

Comment: :::::...thnnks for the answer & helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

The best time would be like if something is already sorted, then no work needs to be done.
The worst case (depends on your algorithm) but think about what would cause your algorithm to take the longest amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

The running time of an algorithm depends on the size and "complexity" of the input.

For example the **best case** running time of insertion sort on an input of some size *n* is proportional to *n*, i.e. *c* * *n* time units for some constant *c* which depends on the cost (time) of comparison, arithmetic, ... of your computing model. The **worst case** running time of this algorithm (insertion sort) is proportional to *n* * *n*. To make a statement for the **average time** we need some assumption on the distribution of the input data: E.g. if the input is random data (and therefore likely not sorted) the average running time is again proportional to n*n.

If you know more about the input data, e.g. that it is sorted with decreasing values (and we are sorting with increasing values) the average running time is stille proportinal to n*n, but the constant factor is higher (because the average searching time for the minimum (which will be inserted at the end of the sorted sub-list) takes longer).

Another, more complex example is quicksort: Its average and best running time for random data is proportional to *n* * log *n*. The worst caste time is still *n* * *n* (often for an already sorted input, but this depends on the algorithm to find the pivot element in the divide step).

Answer (score 1):

worst case is generally denoted by asymptotic notation i.e big(O)

best case is denoted by asymptotic notation i.e big(OMEGA)