# Best/worst case of finding minimum element in an array

Tags: arrays, c, time-complexity, minimum

I am trying to find the minimum element in an array, and I've been asked to figure out the number of comparisons needed while using the naïve approach. So the code I've written is:

```
int findMin(int arr[], int size) {
    int comparisons = 0;
    int temp = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        comparisons++;
        if (arr[i] < temp) {
            temp = arr[i];
        }   
    }
    return comparisons;
}
```

Doesn't this require `n-1` comparisons in all cases? Because I'll have to check all elements from `arr[1]` to `arr[arr_length-1]`, and best case/worst case doesn't come into play as I don't know if the element is minimum unless I encounter all the elements of the array atleast once. Thus, it always does `n-1` comparisons to get to the minimum element right?

One of my friends says its going to be `2(n-2)+1` worst case and `n-1` best case but I don't know how that is? Am I wrong or is something else going on here?

Answer (score 1):

With the unsorted array, since it don't have any information about the order of the unseen element, it have to look at them all, hence the time complexity is `n-1`.

Your algorithm requires `n-1` comparisons in all cases, which means `n-1` in the worst case and also `n-1` in the best case. There are no **optimal inputs** or **pessimal inputs** of your function.

FYI: [What is the best, worst and average case running times of an algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561242/what-is-the-best-worst-and-average-case-running-times-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: Yes thats what I was thinking. Without a sorted input, I wouldnt be able to break ahead of the end of the array, until my algo has seen all elements of the array